# Получение PUSH уведомлений при выключенном приложении

Tags: android-studio, push

сервис myService работает норм (получает инфо с сервера и отдает PUSH уведомления)

теперь цель: выдать PUSH уведомление при **выключенном** приложении, myService не подходит как я понял. Нашел инфу что надо делать через BroadcastReciever (хотелось бы без GCM, firebase).

сделал:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int iduser=0;
        try {
            //вычитываю файл(с телефона) в котором хранятся ID пользователя
            }
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
        if (iduser>0)
        {
        // делаю запрос на сервер через OkHttpClient, получаю данные
        // если есть данные, то отправляю PUSH уведомление 
         NotificationManager.....
         NotificationCompat.Builder
        }

    }
}
```

в манифесте

```
       <service
            android:name="services.myService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="forms.onStartActiv" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <receiver
            android:name="services.MyReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_TICK" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

не могу понять что делать дальше, как сделать так чтоб при выключенном приложении MyReceiver работал в фоне. Надо как я понял его где-то зарегистрировать и что-то прописать, но инфа из инета не помогла (гуглю вторую ночь).
Друзья помогите!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: отправлять PUSH уведомления при выключенном приложении (когда оно не только не активно, но и не запущено).
Пример: если вацап или телеграм не запущены, PUSH уведомления (о новых сообщениях) приходят.
Необходимо аналогичное

Comment: Гугл хотел сделать проще, а получилось как всегда. Чтобы принимать сообщения в сервисе через FCM в любом состоянии приложения - надо отправлять data пуши. Т.е. надо убрать `notification` часть из JSON. Ресивер - устаревший способ, не используйте его.

Comment: без FCM никак ? не очень вас понял

Comment: Решил так: вместо startService поставил startForegroundService для сервиса. Зачем нужен BroadcastReceiver так и не понял. Помогло https://www.dev2qa.com/android-foreground-service-example/